# get bult data with json response

Tags: ios, json, web-services

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: rows1 in **/var/www/html/Oii/webservices/services.php** on line **237**
>
> {"success":1,"Template":[{"template_id":"76","template":"Outside the town"},{"template_id":"74","template":"Love You"},{"template_id":"77","template":"Going to home"},{"template_id":"75","template":"Cant pick up phone"},{"template_id":"73","template":"Call Me"},{"template_id":"78","template":"Busy Right now"}],"Friend":""}

I calling php webservice and it is returning some bult data like this with may json data

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: rows1 in
> **/var/www/html/Oii/webservices/services.php** on line **237**

because of this i not able to serialize this data using this code

```
dicWholeValue=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Comment: This is a problem with your web server, not your iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work, because `iOS` expects pure json data, but your webservice returns some additional information with the data, which the parser won't understand and it fails. The webservice should return only json data that would be **only this part**

`{"success":1,"Template":[{"template_id":"76","template":"Outside the town"},{"template_id":"74","template":"Love You"},{"template_id":"77","template":"Going to home"},{"template_id":"75","template":"Cant pick up phone"},{"template_id":"73","template":"Call Me"},{"template_id":"78","template":"Busy Right now"}],"Friend":""}`

**without**

`Notice: Undefined variable: rows1 in /var/www/html/Oii/webservices/services.php on line 237`

**Ask your webservice developer to remove the warnings, and error.**

All the best.